# Power BI Usage Metrics on Slicers

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to get usage metrics on what users have selected in slicers on my dashboard?

So if a user chooses to slice a page by 2021 or 2022 for example, it is possible to record which years were searched?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can view report statistics under Workspace.

Firstly, find the relating report and click **"View Usage Metrics Report"**.

[image]

Secondly, you can review general statistics for your report. But you can't review specific report visualization metrics.

[image]